# Using find to find largest files

Tags: find, disk-usage

I've been using the command below which works well for finding the largest files in a certain folder.

```
find . -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr | head -10
```

However this provides output in KB only.

```
20160 /home/user/userfile
```

How can I change this command to show me results in MB, or GB? I can do this with `du` and get similar results but I am looking for a way to do this by tweaking the command above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f -exec du -m {} \; | sort -nr | head -10
```

Execute a `du` for each regular file and give the desired option like `-m` for megabyte

Comment: This works great. I was not able to get the numfmt package as suggested in the previous comment.